# JointJS:Hello World example doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jointjs

Hello I'm trying to execute Hello world application using `JointJS` library as given in: http://www.jointjs.com/tutorial#hello-world

I have downloaded `joint.js(1.0.2)` and `joint.css` files, copied the code given in HelloWorld tutorial in html file, and accessed it from the Chrome browser but it's not working as shown in the tutorial.

> Console.error: Uncaught TypeError: this.addCell is not a function

html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="author" content=""/>
<title>diagram</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/joint/joint.min.css">

<body>
   <div id="diaHolder">

   </div>

  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/joint/joint.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
   var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
       el: $('#diaHolder'),
       width: 600,
       height: 200,
       model: graph,
       gridSize: 1
   });

   var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
       position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
       size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
       attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill:       'white' } }
   });

   var rect2 = rect.clone();
   rect2.translate(300);

   var link = new joint.dia.Link({
       source: { id: rect.id },
       target: { id: rect2.id }
   });

   graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `this.addCell`?

Comment: the last line, graph.addCells...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check versions of dependencies, especial Lodash. JointJS it's not compatible with version 4.x

jQuery: 2.2.4
Lodash: 3.10.1
Backbone: 1.3.3

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing this out there but do you have a starting html tag?